# Message box in VB5

Tags: vb5

I have the scenario, The form shall display following message with “OK” , Close option when  a check box ticked with below criteria:
    If date same as the system date
And  Time 4:00 p.m. ET or after

“  date should be changed to next business day.”

I tried :

```
if chk1.vbchecked = true then txtdate.date = now + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Value property:

```
if chk1.Value = 1 then txtdate.date = now + 1
```

Comment: I need to check the criteria 1) date is exactly match the system date, and time > 4pm EST..( next day must be working day)